# Is it bad to echo, output HTML from PHP?

Tags: php, html, echo

I was curious if it's a bad practice to output HTML out of PHP. I'm talking about the fact, that whenever you're doing this, you're letting the system work (which basically is a waste if you're aiming on big applications, right?).

Anyways, what I'm trying to ask is that, whenever I'll be outputting the following:

```
<?php
// Header section
include 'php/header.php';

// Body section
echo '<!-- nav menu -->';
include 'php/sidebar.php';

echo '<h1>Algemene instellingen:</h1>';

echo '<div class="main_content">';
    echo '<form method="POST">';
        echo '<table>';
            echo '<tr><td>Titel:</td><td><input type="" name="ag_title"/></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>Subtitel:</td><td><input type="" name="ag_subtitle"/></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>Verleden:</td><td><input type="" name="ag_past"/></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>Pagina:</td><td><input type="" name="ag_page"/></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>Status:</td><td><input type="" name="ag_status"/></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>Tijdzone:</td><td><input type="" name="ag_timezone"/></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="sbmt_agenda" value="Aanpassen" style="float:right;"/></td></tr>';
        echo '</table>';
    echo '</form>';
echo '</div>';

// Footer section
include 'php/footer.php';
?>
```

If that is a bad practice? (since the form will always be there, and is pretty useless to let the system echo it out).

Comment: _"you're letting the system work"_ what?

Comment: @Epodax Well, echoing out the rules he has to (which are being requested, for example the echo in this case. This will be a higher CPU usage (I guess) then just loading the standard HTML lines (since they're static) right?)

Comment: not bad until you and the next person who will be working on it, understand it.

Comment: @Viral So it wouldn't affect the CPU usage? You're basically telling the system to do something, while having static content, it won't, right?

Comment: PHP is made for that, it's not bad at all to do that but if you don't need to pass php value into html you should close php tag because it'll increase speed of execution

Comment: You can do something better, open one echo and then echo everything instead of echo every lines

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're parsing this with PHP compiler, you use `echo` language construct, you run syntax check for these additional lines. If you don't need to use any variables from PHP in your HTML, then don't use `echo` and insert it after `?>` or before `<?php`.

Also, it's harder to read such code (less space, bad syntax highlighting in some editors) and developer could at first look if there's any logic in that `echo` statements.

*To person who downvoted:
I hope one day you will work with code that misuses `echo` statements.*

Comment: That's right, right? I was thinking, whenever you're telling the system to do something 'it has to think'. So it would be a waste telling the system to do something if you can avoid it.

Comment: Yes, you're wasting CPU.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, ofcourse whenever you're in an IF statement, it would be impossible to print it out in just html, but you could use shortcodes instead, etc. Just trying to figure out how to optimize my code structure the best. Do you have any tips besides this one? :)

Comment: Cache your database queries, `return;` early from functions if condition isn't met, keep your code DRY and avoid many loops if you can do something in one loop.

Comment: What'd you mean by returning, if the condition isn't met? You mean whenever i'm expecting a true, and it's not i'll be returning the function?

Comment: I mean - avoid running logic if you already know the result. I've seen examples letting functions run to the end of function body and returning at the end, even if you could `return` earlier.

Comment: Ah, I see. So for example looping through every single item and expecting the condition true. Whenever you received this one, you'll be exiting the function since 'what you were achieving' already returned?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Statements like `break`, `continue`, `return` can help in such situations.

Comment: Alright, i'll be looking more into that kind of things, you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not bad at all, PHP is "made for that" but you're wasting CPU because the program will try to see if there are some var in the HTML tag which waste CPU if there is none. Also, instead of opening and closing echo at each line, you can open one and close it at the end like

```
echo '<h1>Algemene instellingen:</h1>

<div class="main_content">
// etc
        </table>
    </form>
</div>';
```

But if you don't pass any var in the HTML code, it's better to close it particularly if you have that much HTML code like in your case

Comment: Could you may link me to an explanation of why PHP is made for that?

Comment: No I meant that PHP can interpret HTML tags if they're echo. Other language can't do this that easily. PHP is made for looping or using if statment for HTML. `echo` is a specific thing allowed by php FOR html

Comment: Alright, I get the logic you see. I'll be doing some more research, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is the readability of the code. Somebody else (or you when you've forgotten what the code does) will read it and try to make sense of it. The vast majority of times a couple of extra CPU cycles are well worth sacrificing if the code is easier to read.

So the choice of using echo within PHP or closing the PHP script for plain HTML depends on exactly what the code is doing at that point. Whichever is the easier to read is the best answer.

Comment: It's a project for myself, so i'll be the only one writing / editing the code. Therefore i'd like to have it as optimized as possible. That's why I was asking :)!